# Why does intelliJ freeze when two classes subclasses each other?

Tags: scala, class, intellij-idea

I was wondering what will happen if two classes subclass one another, and I tried it out with Scala using IntelliJ IDEA. The implementation have no errors, but the minute I uncomment out the line inside the `test` object, the IDE just freezes up and theres nothing I can do. What is really happening here?

```
class Shoe extends Table {

}

class Table extends Shoe {

}

object test {
    // val shoe = new Shoe()
}
```

Comment: Read this yet? http://www.geekinterview.com/question_details/85345

Comment: ScalaFiddle says "error: illegal cyclic reference involving class Shoe". I think  that IntelliJ has their own Scala compiler, a bug maybe?

Comment: @insan-e Hmm I guess so. Pretty dangerous considering I didn't even have to run the application, just typing that out caused the IntelliJ to freeze

Comment: @ChanJingHong I tried it also, freezes... :D You should report it! :)

Comment: For me fails to compile **with** error, **without** freezing. (IDEA 2017.2.3, built 2017/08/21)

Comment: @ChanJingHong I do not like you... :D The recent version of IntelliJ 2017.2.3 freezes

Comment: If the IDE freezes, then report a bug. Simple as that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like your version of the IDE is trying to resolve the class structure of your code to identify errors early and/or provide in-scope autocomplete suggestions. But it doesn't seem to have a condition to stop following/identify a recursive subclass.

Make sure to update to the latest version and if that doesn't fix this, file a bug report. Until then, there is probably a setting you can disable in the IDE so it won't freeze trying to resolve the circular class dependency. Corrections and suggestions may lose some accuracy or be completely disabled when you change the autocomplete settings, but it will allow you to run/compile the code to identify the error (a cyclical class dependency) and fix it.

---

A cyclical class dependency is when multiple classes inherit from eachother in a loop. For example, if we have two classes, `class A` and `class B`, we can create a circular dependency loop as shown in this pseudocode:

```
class A inherits B;
class B inherits A;
```

When many compilers or interpreters evaluate this, they see the first line and try to load `B`. To load `B`, they go to its declaration in line 2. Then they see that `A` needs to be loaded. Here, a smart compiler or interpreter will flip a table because it already knows it tried and failed to load `A`. A naive one will happily follow the instructions.

```
load B!
load A!
load B!
load A!
load B!
load A!
```

The smartest compilers and interpreters actually *can* load a circular class dependency and create code that works. But these ones are extraordinarily rare. As a programmer, sometimes it is absolutely essential to have a circular class dependency in languages without this ability.

This is where the idea of class composition comes in. Rather than inheriting a superclass, you can give a working copy of `B` to class `A` in the form of a variable.

Another great option in some cases is to provide a conversion function, allowing `B` to become class `A`; if they both inherit from eachother, it's very likely that they contain the same data despite their different behaviours! Some languages have the built-in ability to do this conversion. The simplest example is a 'typecast'. Some languages also generalize this conversion into parametric polymorphism, where you can write a function that will work on any compatible types without needing to convert them first.

---

Introducing a deviously hard to parse code is always a great way to catch bugs in compilers and interpreters. So keep this snippet in mind for when you have to write and test one!

In some languages stuff like this is, rather than a bug, considered to be Undefined Behaviour. You don't want to mess with Undefined Behaviour in any code you will rely on.

Comment: Having fields or methods or local variables of type `B` in `A` creates a dependency and requires loading `B` just as inheritance does. So if that were the problem, `class Shoe(val t: Table)` + `class Table(val s: Shoe)` wouldn't work either, but it does. Compilers which can deal with this kind of circular dependency are not rare, much less "extraordinarily rare".

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov Fair enough. I'll use more concrete examples in the future so that my statements are more accurate. At least for this answer, a broad overview seemed sufficient to cover the question. It'll be a few days before I'm free to review the subject to improve this answer so feel free to make an edit with corrections or details I may have missed. Thanks for the constructive feedback

Answer (score 1):

Nothing, the compiler rejects this code:

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

class Shoe extends Table {}
class Table extends Shoe {}

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

<pastie>:15: error: illegal cyclic reference involving class Shoe
       class Table extends Shoe {
                   ^
```